# What specifically makes $m_i = 0$ for all $i$ in part $(a)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Here is the question I wanna solve:

Suppose $R$ is commutative and $N \cong R^n$ is a free $R-$module of rank $n$ with $R-$module basis $e_1, \dots , e_n.$

$(a)$ For any nonzero $R-$module $M$ show that every element of $M \otimes N$ can be written uniquely in the form $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} m_i \otimes e_i$ where $m_i \in M.$ Deduce that if $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} m_i \otimes e_i = 0 $ in $M \otimes N$ then $m_i = 0$ for $i = 1, \dots , n.$

$(b)$ Show that if $\sum m_i \otimes n_i = 0$ in $M \otimes N$ where the $n_i$ are merely assumed to be $R$-linearly independent then it is not necessarily true that all the $m_i$ are $0.$ [Consider $R = \mathbb Z, n = 1, M = \mathbb Z/ 2\mathbb Z,$ and the element $1 \otimes 2.$]

**Here is by proof for part(a):**

Let $N \cong R^n $ be a free $R$ module of rank $n$ with $R-$module basis $e_1, \dots , e_n,$ let $R$ be a commutative ring, we want to show that, for every non-zero $R$ module $M,$  $M \otimes N$ can be written uniquely by $\sum m_i \otimes e_i$ where $m_i \in M.$

Now, let $x\in M \otimes N.$ Then, $x=\sum_{j = 1}^p (m^{'}_j \otimes n_j)$ where $n_j= \sum_{i=1}^n r_{ji}e_i$ with $r_{ji} \in R$ (by the definition on pg.$354$ because $N \cong R^n $ is a free $R$ module of rank $n$ with $R-$module basis $e_1, \dots , e_n$). So,

\begin{align*}
x &= \sum_{j = 1}^p (m^{'}_j \otimes (\sum_{i=1}^{n} r_{ji} e_i))\\
&= \sum _{j=1}^p(\sum_{i=1}^{n} r_{ji}m^{'}_j) \otimes e_i \\
&= \sum _{i=1}^n ((\sum_{j=1}^{p} r_{ji}m^{'}_j) \otimes e_i) \\
&= \sum _{i=1}^n m_i \otimes e_i \text{ where $m_i \in M.$ }
\end{align*}

as required. Where the second equality is by the third property of tensor product given in eqn.$10.4$ on pg.$360.$ And the last equality is because $M$ is a nonzero $R-$module.

Note that this form is unique because the $r_{ji}'s$ in the definition of the free module $N$ are unique by the definition of a free module.

Now, assume that $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} m_i \otimes e_i = 0 $ in $M \otimes N$ then because $e_1, \dots , e_n,$ is a basis for $N$ then each of them is nonzero (more explicitly $e_i = (0,0, \dots , 0, 1, 0, \dots, 0)$ where the $1$ appears in the position $i.$) and so for $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} m_i \otimes e_i = 0 $ to be satisfied we must have that $m_i = 0$ for all $i = 1, \dots , n$ as $1 \otimes 0 =  0$ by Example $2$ on pg.$363$ and because tensor product is commutative on commutative rings by proposition $20$ on pg. $374$.

**My questions are:**

The pages in my proof are those of Dummit and Foote, Abstract Algebra, third edition.

1- Is my proof correct regarding to uniqueness part and the proof of the form or should I construct a map like here [Dummit and Foote 10.4.10](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3047280/dummit-and-foote-10-4-10) like this "There is a bilinear map $b:M\times N\to M$ defined by
$$b\left(m,\sum_{i=1}^n r_ie_i\right)=r_1m.$$
This induces a linear map $\beta:M\otimes N\to M$ with
$$\beta\left(m\otimes\sum_{i=1}^n r_ie_i\right)=r_1m.$$
Then $\beta(m_1\otimes e_1)=m_1$ and $\beta(m_i\otimes e_i)=0$
for $i\ne 1$. Then
$$\beta\left(\sum_{i=1}^n m_i\otimes e_i\right)=m_1$$
so $\sum_{i=1}^n m_i\otimes e_i$ determines $m_1$ etc." ?

2- Is my justification for the last part of $(a)$ correct? or What specifically makes $m_i = 0$ for all $i$ in part $(a)$?why when the $n_i's$ are merely assumed to be $R$-linearly independent  it is not necessarily true that all the $m_i$ are $0?$ I feel like I am using **only** the idea of $e_i's$ being basis in my argument.

3- In part$(b),$ what is $N$?

Could anyone help me in answering these questions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't think your proof is really complete. It is true that it follows from the uniqueness of the expansion, but there are steps in between, such as in your link. In that case the map $b$ is well defined because of the uniqueness of the representation.
2. The second part of $a$ follows immediately from the first since

$$\sum_{i=1}^n m_i\otimes e_i = 0 = \sum_{i=1}^n 0\otimes e_i$$

and you just showed that such representations are unique, so $m_i=0$ for each $i$.

3. In $b$ they say $n=1$ which means $N\cong R^1$, so just take $R$ for simplicity. Note that in the given example

$$1\otimes 2 = 1 \otimes (2\cdot1)=(2\cdot1)\otimes 1=0\otimes 1=0$$

so we have that $1\otimes 2=0$ but $m=1\neq0$.

Comment: can you please tell me , for part $(a),$ what is exactly the full proof of it?

Comment: I still can not see why in part $(a)$ the linear independence implies that $m_i = 0$ for all $i$ but the linear independence in $(b)$ does not imply that, could you clarify please?

Comment: what are the "but there are steps in between" you referred to in $1.$?

Comment: @Brain The argument in the other post you linked and copy pasted fills in the details for part $a$, but there are still a few details left. The problem with just linear dependence is that the set may not generate the module and you cannot define the bilinear map described.

Comment: In part $(a),$ the answer in the link does not give me the form that is required ..... it is not clear for me why this should be part of the solution .... please edit your answer with the full correct solution for part $(a)$ so that I can accept it.

Comment: Can you explain how it is not the form that is required?

Comment: this is not the form that is required $$\beta\left(\sum_{i=1}^n m_i\otimes e_i\right)=m_1$$

Comment: If $$\left (\sum_{i=1}^n m_i\otimes e_i\right)=0$$ we have$$\beta\left(\sum_{i=1}^n m_i\otimes e_i\right)=0$$ which means $m_1=0$.Then you can replace the $r_1$ by any $r_i,$ which is enough to show $m_i=0$ for any $i$.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!, so we need the map in the link to prove the last part of $(a)$ only? and the first part of $(a)$ in my proof is correct?

Comment: You correctly showed in $a$ that such a representation exists. The map in the link shows it is unique and my answer shows that if the sum is equal to $0$ each $m_i=0$.